# PHPStorm unable to connect to svn+ssh repository on windows

Tags: windows, svn, ssh, phpstorm

I'm attempting to use PHPStorm's built-in VCS functionality on a windows machine.  When I set it up to utilize svn+ssh, I get the following error:

```
Problems while loading file history: svn: E170012: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'svn+ssh://user@svr/repo_path/trunk'
svn: E170012: Can't create tunnel
svn: E720087: Can't create tunnel: The parameter is incorrect.
```

The repository information is correct and I don't have any issues connecting via TortoiseSVN.  I've attempted to configure it utilizing both TortoisePlink.exe and putty's plink.exe.  I've used both Pageant and tried to provide the key at the command line.

I normally work with OS X and Linux environments, but that's not an option in this case and I'm not exactly sure what to check next and I'm not finding a lot online via google search.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: please see [IDEA-131453](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-131453) - does it look similar?

Comment: It looks similar, though now I just noticed that trying from the command line doesn't work either. It only works with TortoiseSVN and nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue and found this path to the solution: [How to use svn+ssh with Tortoise SVN from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16214136/how-to-use-svnssh-with-tortoise-svn-from-the-command-line)

In context of PhpStorm:
PhpStorm discontinued using SVNKit with svn >= 1.8 so it will not ask for your SSH credentials anymore as it did before but will depend on proper command-line clients to be available and configured.

Now, this works for me:

- Load your private key with Putty pageant (double click on key and enter your password)
- Add a `SVN_SSH` Windows environment variable with content: `C:\\Program Files\\TortoiseSVN\\bin\\TortoisePlink.exe` (Adjust to your path, but **keep the double backslashes!**)

Now, from the command line (restart command line window before trying)
`echo %SVN_SSH%` needs to give you the plink.exe path and you should be able to do a `svn up` on command line without entering your password.

Restart your PhpStorm and SVN should work.

Answer (score 0):

I've spent quite time on the issue, yet still couldn't find the exact problem. One issue is about the 1.8 format of SVN with PhpStorm, it cannot handle the svn+ssh authentication. It is possible to use TortoiseSVN 1.8 but always sticking the 1.7 format in PhpStorm.

My final solution was to install TortoiseSVN 1.7, so that I can use it from the Windows menu as well and no formatting issues happen. Another setting necessary for me was unchecking the option under Version Control > Subversion.

```
[] Use command line client: svn
```

As the ssh executable, I use:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\plink.exe
```