# Maven release:prepare cannot connect to SVN URL

Tags: maven

When I run `mvn release:prepare` in the root directory of my project, I get the following error:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 9.454 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-08-01T10:48:33-04:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 13M/309M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.3.2:prepare (default-cli) on project PROJECT_NAME: Unable to commit files
[ERROR] Provider message:
[ERROR] The svn command failed.
[ERROR] Command output:
[ERROR] svn: E170013: Commit failed (details follow):
[ERROR] svn: E170013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'SVN_URL/PROJECT_NAME/trunk'
[ERROR] svn: E170012: Can't create tunnel
[ERROR] svn: E720002: Can't create tunnel: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

The command that is run just before the error is:

```
Executing: svn --non-interactive commit --file C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\maven-scm-30296160.commit --targets C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\maven-scm-7737565307957865496-targets
```

I can check projects in/out just fine through the Eclipse SVN plugin, but cannot commit to the repository from the command line.

My guess is that Maven doesn't know my SSH key to get access to that repository, even though I have Pageant running. How can I give Maven that info? Or, better yet, how can I run `release:prepare` from Eclipse where I know I can commit to SVN?

**EDIT:** Here's the `<scm>` section of my `pom.xml` file:

```
<connection>scm:svn:SVN_URL/tags/PROJECT_NAME.VERSION</connection>
<developerConnection>scm:svn:svn+ssh://SVN_URL/tags/PROJECT_NAME.VERSION</developerConnection>
<url>SVN_URL/tags/PROJECT_NAME.VERSION</url>
```

Also, anything in all caps is a substitute for privacy concerns.

Comment: Can you post your `<scm>` configuration?

Comment: SVN_URL/PROJECT_NAME/trunk seems like parameters that are not resolved... can you show your pom's <scm>?

Comment: Where can I find my `<scm>` config? And @EldadAK, I substituted the actual URL for privacy reasons.

Comment: Should be inside your `pom.xml`. Maybe in a parent if there's one. Also, do you have Putty or TortoiseSVN installed on your machine? [Check here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16214136/how-to-use-svnssh-with-tortoise-svn-from-the-command-line)

Comment: Post has been updated. I have both Putty and TortoiseSVN. I usually use Pageant to connect to the SVN repo. I can check out files with Tortoise just fine.

Comment: Do you have the `SVN_SSH` environment variable set in your OS [like in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16214136/how-to-use-svnssh-with-tortoise-svn-from-the-command-line)?

Comment: @Tunaki that was it! Can you convert your comment to an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Well all the credit goes to that linked answer really :). It would be more appropriate to flag the post as duplicate of that one - this way, future readers are redirected to the correct answer (without repeating).