# Checkout using SVN on command line

Tags: svn, command-line, tortoisesvn, pageant, svn-checkout

I am using TortoiseSVN with Windows. I checked-out a repository successfully using the explorer integrated client. Authentication works using Pageant and a corresponding key.

Now I want to checkout the same URL using command line. TortoiseSVN bin folder was added to PATH. I copied the URL from the existing working copy and tried to create a new working copy like this:

```
svn checkout svn+ssh://svnuser@192.168.0.1/home/repos/svn/project/trunk ..\Temp
```

And I get:

```
svn: E170013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'svn+ssh://svnuser@192.168.0.1/home/repos/svn/project/trunk'
svn: E170012: Can't create tunnel
svn: E720087: Can't create tunnel: Wrong Parameter.
```

What does the GUI do differently than that? What do I miss?

Comment: Have you already tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16214136/how-to-use-svnssh-with-tortoise-svn-from-the-command-line) ?

Comment: Just tried it and it works. At least it works using windows command line. Using a bash in Windows it did not work but I suppose that's a different problem.